# How do you enable the Ctrl+Alt+Arrow commands for monitor rotation?

Tags: windows-xp, display

I want to rotate a monitor 90 degrees, but the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> command isn't working.

Where is the menu to enable that?

- Monitor: HP L2245wg
- Graphics card: NVIDIA Quadro NVS 285

I actually already have the monitor rotated, but I would like to use the keystrokes in the future rather than digging through eight windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shortcut is typically enabled through the Nvidia control panel. I have no idea if it is also available on ATI cards.

Take a look in the ATI / Nvidia program and see if you can enable it as a option, if it does not support the hotkeys, you should manually be able to rotate the screen.

Answer (score 7):

For Intel Graphics users, right click your Desktop and select **Graphics Options**. Enable/Disable 'Hot Keys' for tackling such issues:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the ctrl+alt+arrow combination you want is from Intels graphics driver. It's not something that's built into Windows XP.

Different manufacturers have different options to enable this and I don't really see anything about Nvidia having this.

Comment: Thanks, I *hate* the ctrl+alt hotkeys, it was screwing up my multiple-desktop app (virtuawin). You helped me find where to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but [iRotate](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm) says it will enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Arrow</kbd> shortcuts for most graphics cards in Windows XP.

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click desktop.
2. Click personalize.
3. Click control panel home on the left of the window that pops open.
4. Click display.
5. Click change display settings on the left of the window that pops open.
6. Where the orientation setting is, change the landscape option to any other option, depending on which way that you want your screen to be.

Comment: Please don't shout! This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).